# Match part of text inside of tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am in client side context.
I have this html:

```
<p>Text text \n other text </p>
```

I want to match only \n element inside paragraph, and replace only this with "br" tag.

I want to do this only inside tag "p" and for all match.

*I supposed to use regex in javascript*.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method with callback and inside callback replace text using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
$('p').html(function(i, htm) {
  return htm.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text text \n other text</p>
```

**UPDATE 1 :** If it's a string then use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```js
console.log(
  '<p>Text text \n other text</p>'.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
)
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :** If the string contains other tag element and you just want to update the `p` tag then do something like.

```js
var str = '<p>Text text \n other text</p>';

console.log(
  // create a temporary div eleemnt 
  $('<div>', {
    // set html content from string
    html: str
  })
  // get all p tags
  .find('p')
  // iterate and replace \n
  .html(function(i, htm) {
    // replace \n with br tag
    return htm.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
  })
  // back to the temp div
  .end()
  // get it's updated html content
  .html()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**UPDATE 3 :** With pure JavaScript by generating a temporary DOM element.

```js
var str = '<p>Text text \n other text</p>';
// create a temporary div element
var div = document.createElement('div');
// set html content form string
div.innerHTML = str;
// get all p tags and convert into Array using Array.from
// for older browser use [].sclice.call instead
Array.from(div.getElementsByTagName('p'))
  // iterate over p tags
  .forEach(function(el) {
    // update the html content
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
  });
// get updated html content
console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry..
I have to correct me
"<p>Text text \n other text </p>" is a string and i get this from another method.

Comment: I want to parse this string. 
And then use parsed html.

Comment: yes..but this string is an example.
This string  may also contains other tags. I want this replace only inside "p" tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop with `getElementsByTagName`:

```
for(i = 0; i < window.document.getElementsByTagName("p").length; i++){
    window.document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML = window.document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML.replace(/\\n/g, "<br/>");
}
```

If this is inside a string and not inside the HTML, you can add it to a `<div>` element while handling it like this:

```
var myString = "<p>Text text \n other text </p>";
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = myString;
for(i = 0; i < div.getElementsByTagName("p").length; i++){
    div.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML = div.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML.replace(/\\n/g, "<br/>");
}
myString = div.innerHTML;
```